# jQuery not working well in firefox and IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Here's code link: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/supermanrocky/HtkAh/6/)

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="first">
<!-- Part one -->
<div class="acord_col">
    <div class="img_class" id="exist_site"></div>
    <div class="intro_text">
    </div>
</div>  
</div>

<div class='total_cost'>
<h1>Your Total Cost is: $<span class="cost_number">0</span><span class="cost_per_page no_display"> + 50/Page</span></h1>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var total_price = 0;

jQuery("#exist_site").click(function() {
            var bg = jQuery(this).css('background');
            var check_string = 'yes.png';

            if (bg.indexOf(check_string) > -1) {
                jQuery(this).css({
                    'background': 'url("http://www.itechinstant.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/home.png")',
                    'background-size': 'cover'
                })
                total_price -= 200;
                jQuery('.cost_number').empty().append(total_price);

                jQuery("#exist_site").hover(function() {
                    jQuery(this).css({
                        'background': 'url("http://www.itechinstant.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/home_h.png)',
                        'background-size' : 'cover'
                    })
                })

                // Change the status of detected value
                var boolean_next = parseInt(jQuery('.boolean_goNext').text());
                boolean_next -= 1;
                jQuery('.boolean_goNext').empty().append(boolean_next);

            } else {
                jQuery(this).css({
                    'background': 'url("http://www.itechinstant.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/yes.png")',
                    'background-size': 'cover'
                })
                total_price += 200;
                jQuery('.cost_number').empty().append(total_price);

                // Change the status of detected value
                var boolean_next = parseInt(jQuery('.boolean_goNext').text());
                boolean_next += 1;
                jQuery('.boolean_goNext').empty().append(boolean_next);

            }

        })
})
```

I was actually coding a price system using jquery.

The question is it works fine in google chrome. But not in firefox and IE11.

When I click the cycle, it should increase the cost, and click again it should deselect the cycle and minus the same cost. It all works fine in chrome. But why in firefox and IE11 the cost keep increasing no matter how many times I click?

Comment: Probably should read the `background-image` property instead of the combined `background` property.  Also looks like every other click will add an additional `.hover()` event handler which is not something you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the **[.css() jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** it says:

> Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, background,
>   border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed.

What we could do is, check for the `background-image` property.

```
var bg = jQuery(this).css('background-image');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57Xyg/)**

Comment: No.  Just read the `background-image` property.  No reason to involve the `background` property at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thought it would make some difference in Chrome, guess it didn't afterall. Thanks for pointing out, updated.

Comment: @Rocky The image seems to disappear after the second click on the yes image after a mouseleave

Comment: @Lekshmi It's because once the tick-mark image comes, he changes it to another image _(which cannot be found)_ on `hover` although it's an inefficient way to bind the element to the hover method multiple times while performing the same job.